# Spinner inside a PopUp Window

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog

I've created a popup window and put a spinner inside it. But I can't get values when an item is selected from it.

My code to create popup:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popwindow=new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addpain, null,false),300,350,true);
    popwindow.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

XML file of PopUp

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#A0BBBBBB">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#A0BBBBBB" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addpaintext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addpain"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/statustbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addpaintext"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:hint="@string/addpain"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addpainbutton"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statustbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:onClick="statusupload"
        android:text="@string/statusupload" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/addpainbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addpainbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:onClick="canceladdpain"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />



    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addpainbutton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statustbox"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:prompt="@string/testtxt"
        android:entries="@array/list"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My StatusUpload Function:

```
public void statusupload(View view)
{

    EditText status=(EditText) popwindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.statustbox); 

    Spinner spinner=(Spinner) popwindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_list);    

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
        {
            category=parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            category="Miscellaneous";
        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),category, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

What happens is the vraible category isnt getting any values !! IT's just blank.

Comment: is it coming up `Miscellaneous`?

Comment: @mango nope nothing !! category variable is just blank empty string

Comment: have you called `public void statusupload(View view)` somewhere?

Comment: @mango nope its just defined in the java source code. ITs connected to button in the PopUp window xml. Button addpainbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not seeing the results you want because everything hinges on the button to turn on your spinner listener. thus you have have to click the button, make a spinner selection, and then click the button again. I'd seriously reconsider the design. For instance, are you aware that you don't need the listener on to get the item selected? you could just use:

```
public void statusupload(View view)
{
    EditText status=(EditText) popwindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.statustbox); 
    Spinner spinner=(Spinner) popwindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_list);    

    category = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),category, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I dunno why i didnt think of it !! Thank You

Comment: Mr Mango, i have tried this, but the first position of spinner only show in toast. i don't know what is the reason it is not working for me. Thanks for Knowledge sharing.